# Direct I/O with C: array vs. pointer

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, io

I need to understand some things about direct I/O in C.  I have a toy code that uses direct I/O to write a character array and it works just fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>


#define MSG_SIZE 4500
#define BLOCK_SIZE 4096

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  char thefile[64];
  int fd;
  int write_success, bytes_to_write, block_size=BLOCK_SIZE;

  // set array size to some multiple of BLOCKSIZE:
  bytes_to_write = ((MSG_SIZE + block_size - 1)/block_size)*block_size;
  char message[bytes_to_write]  __attribute__ ((aligned(BLOCKSIZE)));

  memset(message, 0, bytes_to_write);
  sprintf(message,"The curfew tolls the knell of parting day");
  printf("%s\n", message);

  sprintf(thefile, "diotestfile.dat");

  if ((fd = open(thefile,O_DIRECT | O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRWXU)) == -1) {
          printf("error opening file\n");
          exit(1);
  }
  printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
  write_success = write(fd, message, bytes_to_write);
  printf("write succes?  %s\n", strerror(errno));

  close(fd);


}
```

A `cat` of the output file gives the message.  But I need to be able to do this with a pointer instead an array.  If I redefine `message` as a pointer, that is, I replace

```
char message[bytes_to_write]  __attribute__ ((aligned(BLOCKSIZE)));
memset(message, 0, bytes_to_write);
```

with

```
  char *__attribute__ ((aligned(BLOCKSIZE))) message;
  message = (char *__attribute__ ((aligned(BLOCKSIZE))))calloc(bytes_to_write, sizeof(char));
```

then the `write` function returns an error of `invalid argument`.

The things that haven't worked so far are trying several different alignment sizes, casting `message` to a void pointer in write(), and defining `message` as

```
char *__attribute__ ((aligned(BLOCKSIZE))) message;
```

instead of

```
char *__attribute__ ((aligned(BLOCKSIZE))) message;
```

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `calloc()` doesn't know the alignment requirement.

Comment: My guess is you're going to have to overallocate your `malloc`/`calloc` allocation, then align it yourself, by adding something the the pointer (discarding bytes at the beginning) until you get a pointer to somewhere near the beginning of the block, that satisfies the direct I/O requirements, and also still gives you enough space.

Comment: Declaring the alignment of the pointer variable doesn't make the memory it points to be aligned.

Comment: That is, `char *message = malloc(size + SLOP);`, immediately followed by `message += offset;`, where `offset` is computed such that the new value of `message` satisfies the alignment requirements, and `SLOP >= offset` (for any possible value of `offset`).

Comment: But really: see the dup question that Barmar linked; it explains all of this, and more.